# Hook active trail path views Drupal7

Tags: menu, drupal-7, hook

I' am trying to make a custom module to set an active trail path to a menu.

I created a views page.
The active trail must be to a node or taxonmy term.
When I open the pages created by the view the active trail is not active.

I wrote the script here below but it doesn't work, can somebody please help???

```
function mymodule_views_default_views(&$view, &$display_id, &$args){
  if( $view->name = 'productdetail';)
    {menu_tree_set_path('menu-categorie', 'node/39');
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am happy, I have found the answer to my own question.
I like to share this answer, and hope, that this although helps others...

Here the answer:
In the view I added a field with the term-id / node ID which is although used for my menu and hide the output and do a rewrite of the output
I pasted the following code in text field for rewrite.
field_categorie-tid is my reference term from the menu
menu_tree_set_path('menu-categorie', 'taxonomy/term/[field_categorie-tid]');.
instead of taxonomy term you can although use  node/[nid]

I added in the head section a global field
with php and token and put this script:

Thats all.
No hooks or custom scripting in template

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Script is the wrong word, I used views and added the fields as mentioned above.
Sorry for the misunderstanding. I hope it helps.